# How to serialize NSDictionary containing NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to serialize a NSDictionary which contains an array of NSDictionaries and save it to a file. The code I have is the following (ships is an array of NSDictionaries, and gameOver, paused and level are just booleans or ints; each ship dictionary is just formed by primitive types (no nested dictionaries))

```
private var dictionaryRepresentation: NSDictionary { 
        var ships: [NSDictionary] = []
        for ship in mShips {
            ships.append(ship.convertToDictionary())
        }
        return ["gameOver": gameOver, "paused": paused, "level": level, "ships": ships]
    }

public func save() {
        // Save JSON to file
        var pathURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last
        pathURL = pathURL?.appendingPathComponent("jsoncontent.json")
        let contentDictionary: NSDictionary = dictionaryRepresentation

        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: gameDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
        try! jsonData.write(to: pathURL!)
    }
```

I get an exception in the line

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: gameDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

If I remove the ships key-value it works fine. 
Any hints of what is wrong or an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: What's the error you get? You have a `try`, so what's in the `catch` in case of error? Does `let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: anyShip.convertToDictionar(), options: .prettyPrinted)` works? My guess is that your `convertToDictionar()` doesn't return a JSON Valid dictionary.

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` in Swift 3? Use proper Swift dictionaries.

Comment: Please, don't suffer using `JSONSerialization`. Use the amazing [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Does the ships dictionary contain any custom classes? JSONSerialization cannot convert custom classes to a standard data type. You would get this error if that is the case. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (/*name of your custom class*/)'

Comment: Yes it turns out that the ship container did have a custom class that I had to serialize by hand.